# Can not find processes folder when using spring boot and activiti

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, activiti

I have already put processes folder under resources as [spring boot activiti user guide](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/08/getting-started-with-activiti-and-spring-boot) said. Here is my structure.

[image]

When I use :

```
1. mvn clean package
2. java -jar target/xxx.jar
```

It will raise following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.activiti.spring.boot.SecurityAutoConfiguration$SecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setAuthenticationConfiguration(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.setGlobalAuthenticationConfigurers(java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.activiti.spring.boot.SecurityAutoConfiguration$UserDetailsServiceConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.activiti.engine.IdentityService org.activiti.spring.boot.SecurityAutoConfiguration$UserDetailsServiceConfiguration.identityService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'identityServiceBean' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/spring/boot/JpaProcessEngineAutoConfiguration$JpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngine]: : Error creating bean with name 'processEngine' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/spring/boot/JpaProcessEngineAutoConfiguration$JpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration]: : Error creating bean with name 'springProcessEngineConfiguration' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/spring/boot/JpaProcessEngineAutoConfiguration$JpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration]: Factory method 'springProcessEngineConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [processes/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springProcessEngineConfiguration' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/spring/boot/JpaProcessEngineAutoConfiguration$JpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration]: Factory method 'springProcessEngineConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [processes/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngine' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/spring/boot/JpaProcessEngineAutoConfiguration$JpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration]: : Error creating bean with name 'springProcessEngineConfiguration' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/spring/boot/JpaProcessEngineAutoConfiguration$JpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration]: Factory method 'springProcessEngineConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [processes/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springProcessEngineConfiguration' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/spring/boot/JpaProcessEngineAutoConfiguration$JpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration]: Factory method 'springProcessEngineConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [processes/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

Then when I execute:

```
mvn clean
```

and use idea to run unit test again. It works.

So, why processes folder can not be found when using mvn instead of idea? What is the problem here?

Comment: Are the files located in your jarfile (target/xxx.jar) after you built it?

Comment: Maybe you can post your pom.xml then. At least the `<build>` part of it.

Comment: @stalet  Thank you! It works now with identifying the path of resource !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With @stalet help, I update  part of pom.xml like this:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.properties</include>
            <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Then it worked! Thanks!

Comment: I figured you had a problem with the resource-plugin :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error similar to this issue but not exactly same setup though. The cause was due to not having any process xml files under `src/main/resources/processes/` directory. Once I created a process xml file under the `src/main/resources/processes/` directory, the error is gone.